# After swithing from one project to another programm stop working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-thymeleaf

After swithing from my project to another (for testing purpose) and returing back to my project it stopped work.
I use IDEA IDE, project - Java/Spring/Tomcat/Thymeleaf, browser - Firefox (but the same with Chrome).
So after writing my code I closed my project and opened another one.
After testing it I opened my project and it starting get me an error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 11 12:31:59 EEST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

But I changed nothing in code!
I turned back to another project and it works.
Turns back to my code - that nasty error.(

I read about that error but nothing helps.
I didn't find the same problem's solution.
I really didn't change any symbol in my code.
Just swithed from one project to another.
And now my project doesn't works.

Also I've checked that two of my projects isn't running together. I always manually stops servers. I reloaded my project, reloaded IDE, reloaded PC. Nothing helps.
Changing port also gave nothing.

If I desable whitelabel error by adding `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` into my `application.properties` I have standart Tomcat 404 Not Found Page.

This is the controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("username", "Kate");
        model.addAttribute("color", "red");
        return "home.html";
    }
}
```

And this is html code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome home!

        <span th:style="'color:' + ${color}"
              th:text="${username}">
        </span>
    </h1>
</body>
```

As I mentioned earlier before switching to another project this code worked perfectly.
But now it doesn't.

Comment: Have you ever set the Caches to invalid? Intellij IDEA: FILE | INVALIDATE CACHES  ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your project you were work on before is running.

You can try stop old project and start new project.

Or you can change running `port`.
Insert `server.port=8081` in your `application.properties`. your application will be run at `http://localhost:8081`

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Nope, my project isn't running. I always manually stops servers. I reloaded my project, reloaded IDE, reloaded PC. Nothing helps.
When I insert `server.port=8081` in `application.properties` I have the same result. If I desable whitelabel error by adding `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` into my `application.properties` I have standart tomcat 404 Not Found Page.
PS Eddited my post.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? If not, You can send me your github repo to know more about the problem